# SQL server query to find values grouped by one column but different in at least one of other columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, group-by

Please pardon the title of my question -

I have a table

```
TRXN (ID,ACCT_NUM,TRAN_MEMO,AMOUNT,DATE,LRN)
```

I want to write a query to pull records which have same `LRN` but atleast one of the other column has different value. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my answer I consider you have unique value for ID and exclude it.

Table created:

```
CREATE TABLE #TRXN (ID INT IDENTITY(1, 1)
                    ,ACCT_NUM INT
                    ,TRAN_MEMO INT
                    ,AMOUNT INT
                    ,[DATE] DATE
                    ,LRN INT
)
```

Sample data inserted

```
INSERT INTO #TRXN VALUES (1, 2, 2, '1 jan 2000', 2)
                        ,(2, 2, 2, '2 jan 2000', 2)
                        ,(1, 2, 2, '1 jan 2000', 2)
                        ,(1, 2, 2, '1 jan 2000', 3)
```

Have same LRN but at least one of the other column has different value

```
;WITH C AS(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ACCT_NUM, TRAN_MEMO, AMOUNT, [DATE], LRN ORDER BY ACCT_NUM, TRAN_MEMO, AMOUNT, [DATE], LRN) AS Rn
           ,ID, ACCT_NUM, TRAN_MEMO, AMOUNT, [DATE], LRN
    FROM #TRXN WHERE LRN IN(
    SELECT LRN FROM #TRXN GROUP BY LRN HAVING COUNT(ID) > 1)
)
SELECT ID, ACCT_NUM, TRAN_MEMO, AMOUNT, [DATE], LRN
FROM C WHERE Rn = 1
```

Output:

```
ID ACCT_NUM TRAN_MEMO AMOUNT DATE        LRN
---------------------------------------------
1  1        2         2      2000-01-01  2
2  2        2         2      2000-01-02  2
```

Answer (score 0):

why simply, use group by:

```
 SELECT COUNT(1) AS numberOfGroupedRows,ID,ACCT_NUM,TRAN_MEMO,AMOUNT,DATE,LRN
 FROM TRNX GROUP BY ID,ACCT_NUM,TRAN_MEMO,AMOUNT,DATE,LRN
```

since group by it will group all similar rows in one row

Comment: I want to write a query to pull records which have same LRN but atleast one of the other column has different value.

Comment: provide me simple data of your table